# How to import ipython file in jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have gone through various ways to import a ipython file in jupyter. I am new to it so i have no idea how to import the file.

Code
import SupplyDelay.ipynb as we do in python

Error:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
----> 5 import SupplyDelay.ipynb

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SupplyDelay'

File Hierarchy:
Folder abc:
SupplyDelay
Forecast 
Forecast should import SupplyDelay

Comment: Hi, Could you solve the problem? I have the same problem and  existing solutions don't work.

Comment: Hi @karen_the_great , i am able to solve the problem using the %run magic command. Ii will be enclosing the screen for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the `%run` magic designed to run a notebook from within a notebook? Use like so:

`%run SupplyDelay.ipynb`

If that doesn't work or had undesired side effects, you can also follow the instructions in the docs: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html

Comment: @Davies thanks for suggestion but it doesn't solve my problem. I just want to use certain features of the file. Not to run the entire file.

Comment: This solution adds .py to the name and doesn't import the ipynb. Any ideas why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Here i have created two .ipynb file
1. Master.ipynb
2. Child.ipynb

The Master.ipynb looks something like this

[image]

Here i have defined few functions.

Now i have created the Child.ipynb in the same directory as Master.ipynb, the following snip shows how to call Master.ipynb from the Child.ipynb

[image]

Hope, this solves your problem.